# Code compiles while breaking generics constraint on return type

Tags: java, generics

String does not implement AutoCloseable, so how can we assign the result of my method "get" to a String? Does anyone know why this compiles under Java 8 and 11?  If I swap AutoCloseable with a non-interface class like Integer, I get the compiler error I expected.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        final String result = new Foo().get(0);
    }
}

class Foo {

    List<AutoCloseable> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public <A extends AutoCloseable> A get(int name) {
        return (A) list.get(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the result of the type inference is "a type that both extends String and implements AutoClosable". I don't think it considers the fact that String is final when it does type inference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't provide the type argument explicitly, it's being inferred (see [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-18.html))) allowing `String` to be one of the valid return types.

I assume it gets resolved to a more permissive type (see [`AdditionalBound`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)) taking into account the type of the variable it's going to be assigned to and the bounds you declared.

Something like

```
String & AutoCloseable
Integer & AutoCloseable
<Anything Really> & AutoCloseable
```

It changes if you set the type argument explicitly

```
String autoCloseable = new Foo().<AutoCloseable>get(0);
```

resulting in a compilation error.

Comment: So when I use an interface in the generics constraint, there's a possibility that the return type might both be assigned to my variable and implement the given interface? If only String was not final... I think I understand. Thank you!